# Using panel cointegration techniques in cross country regressions

Tags: multivariate-analysis, panel-data, cointegration

I am looking to assess inequality's impact on growth. I am using panel data consisting of approximately 25 years in 60 countries and will be including inequality and two controls as regressors. I am wondering are heterogeneous panel cointegration techniques appropriate in this context? And what are the factors I should be considering when assessing if this sort of technique would be appropriate?

Comment: You may find these useful: De Boef, S. and Keele, L. (2008). [Taking time seriously](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3a3e/d25148f942dc6038a1fb45bcb759575106a4.pdf). *American Journal of Political Science*, 52(1):184–200. and Keele, L. and Boef, S. D. (2006). [Not Just for Cointegration: Error Correction Models with Stationary Data](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/32fa/a6da80e2e8361bf6c650e11a2033d8b3b88b.pdf). Unpublished manuscript.